# Ubuntu 12.10 Crontab to start Vino VNC Server

Tags: ubuntu, cron, vnc, xserver

I want to start the vino VNC server ( vino-server ) from the crontab on reboot on Ubuntu 12.10.

My crontab entry looks like:

```
## Start the vino server
@reboot sleep 20 ; /home/user/Desktop/start_vino_vnc.sh
```

My script looks like:

```
#! /bin/bash

export DISPLAY=:0.0
xhost +
nohup /usr/lib/vino/vino-server > /home/user/Desktop/vino_log.txt
```

I constantly get the following errors in my log file:

```
user@user:~/Desktop$ cat vino_log.txt 
No protocol specified
Cannot open display: 
Run 'vino-server --help' to see a full list of available command line options
```

From the command line if I try to run the server without SSH'ing with X Server forwarded then I get the same error:

```
user@user:~/Desktop$ /usr/lib/vino/vino-server 
No protocol specified
Cannot open display: 
Run 'vino-server --help' to see a full list of available command line options
```

How can I achieve this? I need this to happen via crontab and there is no monitor on the headless Ubuntu server.

Comment: If you want a script to execute on restart, you do not have to use crontab. Crontab is for specific time execution. What you need is to create a startup script in `/etc/init.d`

Comment: OK - thanks for the input. As far as setting the DISPLAY variable correctly - how do I do that? I can certainly start the script any way but even if I just run my script from the command line I get the same error shown above.

Comment: On Ubuntu 16 this worked for me https://stackoverflow.com/a/31710029/543087

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was a command line option for setting the display - for me it worked to set that option:

```
#! /bin/bash

export DISPLAY=:0.0
xhost +
nohup /usr/lib/vino/vino-server --display=:0.0 > /home/pclass/Desktop/vino_log.txt
```