# Linux bash shell script output is different from cronjob vs manually running the script

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I wrote a linux bash shell script which works fine except the output when I run it manually is different than when I run it from a cronjob.

The particular command is `lftp`:

```
lftp -e "lcd $outgoingpathlocal;mput -O $incomingpathremote *.CSV;exit" -u $FTPUSERNAME,$FTPPASSWORD $FTPSERVER >> ${SCRIPTLOGFILE} 2>&1
```

When I run the script manually, the `${SCRIPTLOGFILE}` contains a lot of info such as how many files/bytes/etc transferred.  But when I run the same script from a cronjob there is no output unless there was an error (such as could not connect). I have tried various terminal output configurations but none work for this `lftp` command.  Suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

It's worth reading this:

[crontab PATH and USER](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10129381/crontab-path-and-user)

In particular, cron won't set the same environment variables you're used to an interactive shell.

You might want to wrap your entire cron job up in a script, and then you can, for example, temporarily add some code like `export >> scriptenvironment.txt` and see what the difference is between the cron invoked script and the interactively invoked script.

Try `man 5 crontab` for details.

Once you know what envrionment variables you need for your script to run, you can set them in the crontab as necessary, or source at the start of your own script.

```
 EXAMPLE CRON FILE
 # use /bin/sh to run commands, overriding the default set by cron
 SHELL=/bin/sh
 # mail any output to `paul', no matter whose crontab this is
 MAILTO=paul
 #
 # run five minutes after midnight, every day
 5 0 * * *       $HOME/bin/daily.job >> $HOME/tmp/out 2>&1
 # run at 2:15pm on the first of every month -- output mailed to paul
 15 14 1 * *     $HOME/bin/monthly
 # run at 10 pm on weekdays, annoy Joe
 0 22 * * 1-5    mail -s "It's 10pm" joe%Joe,%%Where are your kids?%
 23 0-23/2 * * * echo "run 23 minutes after midn, 2am, 4am ..., everyday"
 5 4 * * sun     echo "run at 5 after 4 every sunday"
```