# Ubuntu: Starting a shell script with args at boot

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu

I'm running Ubuntu Server 14.04 and I'm trying to get a shell script to run at boot. The problem is the script requires args, one of which is a file (a database) and the other is a port number which is found in the same folder as the script. I'm fairly new to this.

When I go in the folder in terminal for example, I can type:

```
sh script.sh potato 1234
```

script.sh is the script, potato is the filename, and **1234** is the port number. Works fine when I do it manually.

I tried adding a crontab, @reboot script.sh potato 1234, of course it didn't work, it couldn't find the script.

So I tried:

```
 @reboot */path/to/my/script.sh* potato 1234
```

again, didn't work. Figured it couldn't find the database.

So I tried:

```
@reboot path/to/my/script.sh /path/to/my/potato 1234
```

Still no dice.

I tried running it in term with paths as well

```
sh path/to/my/script.sh potato 1234
```

of course failed - the script up and told me it couldn't find the db, as it should.

`sh /path/to/my/script.sh /path/to/my/potato 1234` returned no errors, but it didn't start either.

This is what the script I'm trying to start looks like:

```
if [ $# -lt 1 -o $# -gt 2 ]; then
    echo 'Usage: restart dbase-prefix [port]'
    exit 1
fi

if [ ! -r $1.db ]; then
    echo "Unknown database: $1.db"
    exit 1
fi

if [ -r $1.db.new ]; then
    mv $1.db $1.db.old
    mv $1.db.new $1.db
    rm -f $1.db.old.Z
    compress $1.db.old &
fi

if [ -f $1.log ]; then
    cat $1.log >> $1.log.old
    rm $1.log
fi

echo `date`: RESTARTED >> $1.log
nohup ./moo $1.db $1.db.new $2 >> $1.log 2>&1 &``
```

Any clues?

Comment: Run `sh -x /path/to/my/script.sh /path/to/my/potato 1234` and see what you get as the commands that are being run? Where does it stop/fail?

Comment: Thanks for looking! It's: `+ [ 2 -lt 1 -o 2 -gt 2 ]
+ [ ! -r /path/to/my/potato.db ]
+ [ -r /path/to/my/potato.db.new ]
+ mv /path/to/my/potato.db /path/to/my/potato.db.old
+ mv /path/to/my/potato.db.new /path/to/my/potato.db.db
+ rm -f /path/to/my/potato.db.old.Z
+ [ -f /path/to/my/potato.log ]
+ cat /path/to/my/potato.log
+ rm /path/to/my/potato.log
+ compress /path/to/my/potato.db.old
/path/to/my/script.sh: 32: /path/to/my/script.sh: compress: not found
+ date
+ echo Sun Nov 22 23:08:07 GMT 2015: RESTARTED
root@moodev:/# + nohup ./moo /path/to/my/potato.db /path/to/my/potato.db.new 7777`

Comment: I cannot into linebreaks. New to asking questions here as well. It seems to be crapping out at compress. Lemme see if it craps out there if I run the script in its folder.

Comment: This is what I get with -x directly in its folder.. `+ [ 2 -lt 1 -o 2 -gt 2 ]
+ [ ! -r potato.db ]
+ [ -r potato.db.new ]
+ [ -f potato.log ]
+ cat potato.log
+ rm potato.log
+ date
+ echo Sun Nov 22 23:18:40 GMT 2015: RESTARTED`

Comment: So..I could simply remove the compress execution from the script.sh (mostly pointless, the DB won't ever exceed a couple hundred mb) and it should work? Or replace it with tar...hm. Science.

Comment: Edit the output into the script so you can format it correctly.

Comment: Commenting out the compress line in the script made it not return the error but also did not execute. Going to try to reformat the previous comments with the output

Comment: Sounds like you don't have a `compress` binary. Which isn't all that surprising as `compress` is fairly obsolete at this point as there are *many* newer compression methods which are better.

Comment: `+ [ 2 -lt 1 -o 2 -gt 2 ] 
+ [ ! -r /path/to/my/potato.db ] 
+ [ -r /path/to/my/potato.db.new ] 
+ mv /path/to/my/potato.db /path/to/my/potato.db.old 
+ mv /path/to/my/potato.db.new /path/to/my/potato.db.db 
+ rm -f /path/to/my/potato.db.old.Z 
+ [ -f /path/to/my/potato.log ] 
+ cat /path/to/my/potato.log 
+ rm /path/to/my/potato.log 
+ compress /path/to/my/potato.db.old /path/to/my/script.sh: 32: /path/to/my/script.sh: compress: not found 
+ date 
+ echo Sun Nov 22 23:08:07 GMT 2015: RESTARTED root@moodev:/# 
+ nohup ./moo /path/to/my/potato.db /path/to/my/potato.db.new 7777`

Comment: Yep, still won't take my line breaks. Hrm.

Comment: Yeah, I don't really care about compressing the old file. So I commented out that line, it executed without error with the paths but the process that's supposed to start didn't (not showing in `top` like it usually does). Running the script directly from its folder however starts it, and I can connect with the client software on port 7777, and it shows in `top`

Comment: Okay, so I fixed this by realizing cron runs everything in term anyway. So, @reboot cd /path/to/my/; ./restart.sh potato 7777. Tested and it works.

Comment: In that case it should've been a question on SU.. lol

Answer (score 1):

You need to see the output of your program. `cron` mails the output to the owner of the crontab or to the address specified in the `MAILTO` environment variable, on top of the crontab.

Be careful about execution environment. Typically, most of the basic environment variables (`PATH`, `HOME`, etc.) will not be set, and might lead to execution errors.

For more information, see the `cron` man page:

```
man 5 crontab
```

These posts might also help you :

- [crontab PATH and USER](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10129381/crontab-path-and-user)
- [Where are cron errors logged?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/207/where-are-cron-errors-logged)