# Send e-mail using command line and save IP rules

Tags: shell, email, sendmail

I am coding a script to select some IPs from a table in a DB, and then use IPTables rules to ban theses IPs, last step is to notify by e-mail, but I am getting 2 errors:

```
#!/bin/bash

Now=$(date +"%d-%m-%Y %T")

fileLocation="/var/lib/mysql/DBName/"
fileName="ip2ban.txt"
filePath=$fileLocation$fileName
curLocation=$(pwd)

#Connect to DB and select ban_ip
mysql -u root -pPASSWORD -D DBName -e 'SELECT ip INTO OUTFILE "'$filePath'" FROM ban_ip WHERE ip_tables = "0"' >> banIP.log 2>&1

selRes=$?

# If the command was successful
if [ $selRes -eq "0" ]
then   

    # We need to check if the file exists on the saved location
    #find $fileLocation -type f -iname "ip2ban.txt" -empty => To check if file empty or not

    if [ -f $filePath ]
then   
    mv $filePath $curLocation'/ip2ban.txt'

    # Connect to DB and update the ban_ip
    mysql -u root -pPASSWORD -D DBName -e 'UPDATE ban_ip SET ip_tables = "1" WHERE ip_tables = "0"' >> banIP.log 2>&1

     upRes=$?

    if [ $upRes -eq "0" ]
            then

    # Send message for succesful result
    echo -e "Database updated with new banned IPs on $Now \nThank you for using this script" 2>&1 | sed '1!b;s/^/To: myID@gmail.com\nSubject: New banned IPs[Success]\n\n/' | sendmail -t

    else

    # Send message for failure result
    echo -e "We cannot update the ban_ip table on $Now \nThank you for using this script" 2>&1 | sed '1!b;s/^/To: myID@gmail.com\nSubject: [Failure] New banned IPs\n\n/' | sendmail -t

    fi

fi

else
    echo 'Something wrong with Select statment on' $Now >> banIP.log
fi

# Save IPTables rules
iptables-save > /root/Scripts/IPTables/BannedIPs.conf // LIGNE 53
```

I am getting 2 errors:

```
line 53: iptables-save: command not found 
line 37: sendmail: command not found
```

However the sendamil is already installed, with mail, postfix:

```
# which sendmail
/usr/sbin/sendmail

# which mail
/usr/bin/mail

# which postfix
/usr/sbin/postfix
```

Thanks for your usual support

Comment: What is the value of $PATH when this script executes? I assume you are running this as the root user?

Comment: I think as user, it is on crontab, even I try as a command line to send mail, it Does NOT work

Comment: I don't think you will be able to get ``iptables-save`` working unless you are root user. So you would need to tell cron to run it as root. You will need to be root if you want to make changes to iptables.

Comment: How can I tell to cron to run it as a root?

Comment: Run it from `root`'s crontab, or grant yourself the necessary privileges with `sudo`.  Maybe create a dedicated pseudo-user with only this privilege and run this script from that user's crontab.

Comment: I am identifying as root, then I type crontab -e, then I put the rules over there, it is running under root privileges

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [crontab(5)](http://www.unix.com/man-page/Linux/5/crontab/) man page for Linux:

> PATH  is  set to "/usr/bin:/bin".

Meaning your shell script will not be able to find anything under /usr/sbin or /sbin. Change this with by adding the following near the top of your script:

```
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
```

Also the environment can be set from within the crontab. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/14694543/5766144 for how to do this.

Comment: I added the line on the top of my script, I am waiting for the cron to be executed, so I can have an answer

Comment: For mail sending, I edited the file main.cf for postfix, I commented the line #inet_protocols = all, and now it works fine

Comment: It works like a charm, I even test it using the proper path which is /sbin/save-iptables, and works file, thanks dude