# Can't run reboot on Ubuntu from Java

Tags: java, cron

I can't run the reboot command from Java on a Ubuntu PC from a cronjob but when calling it directly from the terminal it works.

Has anybody an idea what the problem is?

This is my code:

```
private static void reboot() throws IOException {
        Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
        runtime.exec("reboot");
        System.exit(0);
}
```

And this the error when execution with cron:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "reboot": error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1048)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:620)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:450)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:347)
    at xyz.stankovic.nikola.minermaintenanceagent.App.reboot(App.java:40)
    at xyz.stankovic.nikola.minermaintenanceagent.App.main(App.java:32)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.forkAndExec(Native Method)
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.<init>(UNIXProcess.java:247)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:134)
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1029)
    ... 5 more
```

Comment: Do you need to set the `PATH` environment variable appropriately?

Comment: Why do you think this is required? I use the full path to access the jar.

Comment: This is a very typical problem for things run under `cron` - see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10129381/crontab-path-and-user