# How to run sacct command in shell script

Tags: bash, shell, cron, slurm

I am trying to write a cron that will run sacct command of slurm for given dates and save it in file. As I don't have much experience with shell script I am not sure how to do it.

I did the following:
I created a shell script with the following code (sacct_data.sh):

```
#!/bin/bash
startdate=`date +"%Y-%m-%dT00:00:00"`
enddate=`date -d "yesterday" '+%Y-%m-%dT00:00:00'`

TZ=UTC sacct info_that_needs_to_be_pulled --starttime $startdate --endtime $enddate > data.log
```

In the crontab I have the following code:

```
* * * * * bash sacct_data.sh #I know this will run every min, but that's is not important
```

However, I am getting the error "sacct: command not found".

Any help is appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `sacct: command not found` error means that the command was not found in the PATH. And that is expected as the PATH set in cron environments is really minimal. You can either set a correct PATH variable (see [this for instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10129381/crontab-path-and-user)) or use the [absolute](https://www.linux.com/training-tutorials/absolute-path-vs-relative-path-linuxunix/) `sacct` path: type `which sacct` and use the output in `sacct_data.sh`.